# ASP.NET MVC code-first authentication page, can not upload files

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created an ASP.NET MVC project with authentication and I want to add a new field to register page for uploading an user image. The problem is when I save the new account, the image column is empty.

After some digging, I found that the file is not transmitted from the view to the model (`model.Image` is always null).

These are the steps I have done:

1. I updated the identity `Models.cs` and added

   ```
   public byte[] Image { get; set; }
   ```
2. I updated the database with the new column (of type `varbinary(max)`)
3. In `AccountViewModels`, I created

   ```
   [Display(Name = "Image")]
   public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }
   ```
4. In `Register.cshtml` I inserted:

   @model ProiectSiteCIG.Models.RegisterViewModel
   @{
   ViewBag.Title = "Register";
   }

   @ViewBag.Title.

   ```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
       @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Fotografie, new { @class = "col-md-2 col-form-label" })
       <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Image, new { @class = "form-control", type = "file", name = "Image" })
       </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="offset-md-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Inregistrare" class="btn btn-outline-dark" />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
   ```

   @section Scripts {
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
   }
5. In the `AccountController`, I wrote the following code

   ```
   public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
   {
       byte[] data;

       if (model.Fotografie != null)
       {
           using (Stream inputStream = model.Fotografie.InputStream)
           {
               MemoryStream memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;

               if (memoryStream == null)
               {
                   memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                   inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
               }

               data = memoryStream.ToArray();
           }
       }
       else 
           data = null;

       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           var user = new ApplicationUser 
                      {
                          UserName = model.Email,
                          Email = model.Email,
                          Image = data, 
                      };
       }
   }
   ```

I tried every combination on StackOverflow and Google and I come to the conclusions:

1. I don't understand how data is transmitted or
2. I am missing something

Comment: Does the form has the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute?

Comment: @VDWWD I updated the cshtml with the first lines of code. I inserted the enctype....

Answer (score 0):

Your property, where uploaded image data are located, is **"Image"** not "Fotografie", so you must modify your action like that:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    byte[] data;

    if (model.Image != null && model.Image.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        using (Stream inputStream = model.Image.InputStream)
        {
            MemoryStream memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;

            if (memoryStream == null)
            {
                memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            }

            data = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
    else 
        data = null;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser 
                   {
                       UserName = model.Email,
                       Email = model.Email,
                       Image = data, 
                   };
    }
}
```

Change, and it will work...